# Scala + Lift: Ambigous implicit conversions when parsing XML

Tags: xml, scala, lift

I have a method that extracts action-objects from an xml-Node:

```
    private def appendActionsFromXml(device: Device, xml: Node) = {
    xml \ "actions" \ "action" map {
        x => {
            val key = x \ "@key" text
            val value = x \ "@value" text
            device.createAction(key, value)
        }
    }
}
```

However, since I have imported import net.liftweb.json.JsonDSL._ in the same class, I get an ambigouity when I extract the "@key"-attribute from x:

```
[INFO] Note that implicit conversions are not applicable because they are ambiguous
[INFO]  both method string2jvalue in trait Implicits of type (x: String)net.liftweb.json.JsonAST.JString
[INFO]  and method augmentString in object Predef of type (x: String)scala.collection.immutable.StringOps
[INFO]  are possible conversion functions from String to ?{val apply: ?}
[INFO]  val value = x \ "@value" text
```

How do I resolve this ambigouity in this perticular method?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
val key: String = x \ "@key" text
val value: String = x \ "@value" text
```

Answer (score 0):

Move your JsonDSL-import (or reversely the XML-imports) into a smaller scope if possible.

```
class A {
  def doXmlStuff = { ... }
  def doJsonStuff = {
    import net.liftweb.json.JsonDSL._
    ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually the way to resolve this kind of problem is to reduce the scope of the import.  In this case perhaps you don't need to have `net.liftweb.json.JsonDSL._` in scope within the scope that encloses `appendActionsFromXml`.  Hard to say if that would work without seeing more context.